# VSCode - Cmd+Shift+E & Cmd+Shift+F stopped working on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have used VSCode for years and frequently use Cmd+Shift+E to see the explorer panel and Cmd+Shift+F to find files, but the functionality stopped working a few days ago.

I'm do not think I have accidentally changed any keybindings, and wondering if an upgrade to VSCode is the reason.

I usually can press:

**OLD**:

Cmd+Shift+E (press once only) would always go to Explorer, and other collapsable elements like Search would disappear.

**NOW**:

**A:** if File Explorer is collapsed, then Cmd+Shift+E goes to Search and does not show the File Explorer

[image]

**B:** If File Explorer is not collapsed, Cmd+Shift+E goes to Explorer, but the Search area is still showing.

[image]

**OLD**:

Cmd+Shift+F (press once only) would always go to the file Search, and collapsable elements like file explorer would disappear.

**NOW**:

**A:** If File Explorer is collapsed, Cmd+Shift+F goes to Search (This is expected)

[image]

**B:** if File Explorer is not collapsed and Cmd+Shift+F is pressed, it goes to Search and leaves the file explorer visible. (File Explorer used to disappear)

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had accidentally dragged the docked search view in to the explore view.

I was able to resolve my issue by resetting all view locations

`CMD + SHIFT + P` => `Reset View Locations`